# What advantage has JPA 2.1 @ConstructorResult and @SqlResultSetMapping over JPQL SELECT NEW SomeConstructor(...)?

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.1

I'm wondering what's the benefit of using @SqlResultSetMapping and @ConstructorResult? Is it better, and if, why, from using JPQL SELECT NEW SomeConstructor ?

For example, is that better:

```
@Table(name = "person")
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMappings(
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "contactLess", 
        classes = @ConstructorResult(columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "full_name", type=String.class)
        }, targetClass = Person.class)
    )
)
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Person.findWithoutContacts",
                   query = "SELECT c.id, c.full_name FROM person c ",
              resultSetMapping = "contactLess", resultClass = Person.class)
})
```

than this ( spring data in this case):

```
@Query("SELECT NEW Person(c.id, c.fullName) FROM Person c")
public List<Person> findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have several JPQLs (and/or query builders) refering to one entity, than using annotations will make your code easier to refactor. JPQL also has no compile safety.

Comment: I agree that it makes it easier to refactor, but isn't \@SqlResultSetMapping and \@ConstructorResult also not compile-safe? Are there any other reasons to use \@ConstructorResult? It uses native sql, when JPQL is platform independent, am I right?